# Cannot load Bootstrap 4 from a CDN

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari, cdn

Linking from a CDN gives me a weird-looking navbar. Linking from local files, however, gives me the correct output.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>base template title</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse mb-4">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Top navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

I'm using Safari Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34) under macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4 (16E195)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your local version the same `4.0.0-alpha.6` version?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, I just cloned their Github repo last night.

Comment: Then it's **not** the same version if you didn't explicitly check out the tagged release. `4.0.0-alpha.6` was released on Jan 6. There have been several hundred commits since then.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh that's it……So there's some errors in my HTML code? Actually I copy-and-pasted most of it from an example in the Github repo.

Comment: It's an alpha - lots of things subject to change, including the HTML structure for something like a navbar. You really don't want to be using the BS4 alpha for anything important - it's not stabilized yet.

Comment: @ceejayoz OK, going to rollback to Bootstrap 3……

Comment: @ceejayoz I've solved my problem now, but I still think you should post an answer, so that I can upvote and accept it. Also, for other people who have a similar issue, reading an answer would be much easier than digging for information in the comments.

Comment: This HTML as posted is invalid actually, including no closing body tag